# Android 3d Animation Imageview

Tags: android

I have few doubts regarding the 3d Animation Image View on android.i have created one Image View in my application.But i need rotate the Image View in 3d its is possible in android. please help me for this.
Regards
Raj.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below links may help you..

[3d transition](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/animation/Transition3d.html)

[android viewgroup roation in 3d](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5398882/android-viewgroup-rotation-in-3d)